# warning: no previous prototype for 'usage'

Tags: c

```
int /usage( const char* name )
{
   fprintf( stderr, "usage: %s\n", name );

   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -h a | c ]\n"
            "\t\thealthcheck - amf or comp invoked\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -e a | s | q | r | p | x ]\n"
            "\t\terror assignment (x error all)\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -f invocation_number ]\n"
            "\t\tfail specified healthcheck invocation\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -i a | s | q | r | p | x ]\n"
            "\t\tignore assignment (x ignore all)\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -m b]\n"
                    "\t\tpassive monitoring - start\n");
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -p proxied ]\n"
            "\t\tregister for proxied\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -s ]\n"
            "\t\tsuppress component output\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -z ]\n"`enter code here`
            "\t\tsuppress component registration\n" );
   return 1;
}
```

Please help me to get rid of that warning. As I am facing this from few days. Have many more warnings of same type. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have a stray `\` in the signature of your function, it cannot be there:

```
int usage( const char* name )
{
   fprintf( stderr, "usage: %s\n", name );

   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -h a | c ]\n"
            "\t\thealthcheck - amf or comp invoked\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -e a | s | q | r | p | x ]\n"
            "\t\terror assignment (x error all)\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -f invocation_number ]\n"
            "\t\tfail specified healthcheck invocation\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -i a | s | q | r | p | x ]\n"
            "\t\tignore assignment (x ignore all)\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -m b]\n"
                    "\t\tpassive monitoring - start\n");
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -p proxied ]\n"
            "\t\tregister for proxied\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -s ]\n"
            "\t\tsuppress component output\n" );
   fprintf( stderr, "\t[ -z ]\n"
            "\t\tsuppress component registration\n" );
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have '\' in my code. That was my mistake. Still facing the warning. Help me out

Comment: @Mitra then you haven't posted all your code, because the warning you speak of, I can't reproduce with the code you have posted.

Comment: void format_SaNameT( const char* const name, SaNameT* formatted )
{
   if( ! name || ! formatted ) return;

   memset( formatted, 0, sizeof( SaNameT ) );
   formatted->length = strlen( name );
   strncpy( formatted->value, name, SA_MAX_NAME_LENGTH );
}